# Selenium chrome headless script dosent work

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Chrome Version 106.0.5249.62

So i tried making an script with selenium to download certain files, while chrome runs in headless - mode.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://domain.tld")

# use delay function to get all tags
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
# identify username, password and signin elements
driver.find_element_by_name("usernamefld").send_keys("xxxxx")
time.sleep(0.2)
driver.find_element_by_name("passwordfld").send_keys("xxxxx")
time.sleep(0.6)
driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()
driver.get("https://domain.tld/download")
driver.get("https://domain.tld/download")
driver.close
```

Thats the message i get after i run it.

```
<bound method WebDriver.close of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="cefc531f976a77009071fa49425c6d39")>>
```

For some reason it dosent download the 2 files, nothing happens.
So what did I do wrong?

Comment: Does this code work in normal mode?

Comment: @Prophet yes work in normal mode without any issues

Answer (score 0):

did you try implementing this code?

```
ser = Service("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by supporting information about how/why it solves the problem.